# Simulating Key Press C#

Tags: c#

I want to simulate <kbd>F5</kbd> key press in my C# program. When IE is open, I want to be able refresh my website automatically.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is this a web app or a desktop app?

Comment: In that case I think Mr. Bondy has hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Here's an example...

```
static class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Process [] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");

            foreach(Process proc in processes)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                SendKeys.SendWait("{F5}");
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

a better one... less anoying...

```
static class Program
{
    const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const int VK_F5 = 0x74;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Process [] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");

            foreach(Process proc in processes)
                PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This (especially the "better" one) has helped me, +1. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16255097/385995) to see a more complex example that also involves modifier keys.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the Win32 API `FindWindow` or [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500(VS.85).aspx) to find the window handle of the open browser and then just call [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) with [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280(VS.85).aspx).  Typically it's easiest just to pass the window caption to `FindWindowEx` and have it find the associated window handle for you.

If you are starting the browser process yourself via a `Process process` object then you can use `process.MainWindowHandle` instead of calling `FindWindowEx`.

Spy++ is a very useful tool when you want to start working with other windows.  It basically allows you to learn another program's hierarchy of UI elements.  You can also monitor all of the messages that go into the window you're monitoring. I have more info in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604898/net-sendkeys-to-calculator).

The F5 keystroke has this virtual key code:

```
const int VK_F5 = 0x74;
```

The p/invoke signature for `FindWindowEx` in C# is:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
```

You can p/invoke (bring in) the Win32 API `SendMessage` like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

So to recap, you call `FindWindowEx` directly from your C# code after having the above code somewhere inside your class.  `FindWindowEx` will return a window handle. Then once you have the window handle, you can send any keystroke(s) to the window, or call many other Win32 API calls on the window handle.  Or even find a child window by using another call to `FindWindowEx`.  For example you could select the edit control of the browser even and then change it's text.

If all else goes wrong and you think you're sending the right key to the window, you can use `spy++` to see what messages are sent to the window when you manually set focus to the browser and manually press `F5`.

Comment: Can you be more detailed please, I'm really dont know how to use Win32 API.

Comment: The link to the SO thread is pretty much perfect. But also perhaps this snippet might help - http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4070

Comment: @Dani: I added more info, but you can search Google code search with lang:c# for more detailed examples.  http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=lang:c%23+FindWindowEx&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code

Comment: This answer is direly missing a useful example. How would you use the function and where would you define it? What are the attributes in `SendMessage` supposed to be?

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to send  (simulate) KeyStrokes to any window is to use the SendKeys.Send method of .NET Framework.

Checkout this very intuitive MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

---

Particularly for your case, if your browser window is in focus, sending F5 would just involve the following line of code:

```
SendKeys.Send("{F5}");
```

Comment: SendKeys is undefined

Comment: Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.

Answer (score 7):

Use mouse_event or keybd_event. They say not to use them anymore but you don't have to find the window at all.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class SimulatePCControl
{

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void keybd_event(uint bVk, uint bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

private const int VK_LEFT = 0x25;

public static void LeftArrow()
{
    keybd_event(VK_LEFT, 0, 0, 0);
}

}
```

Virtual Key Codes are here for this one: http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html

Also for mouse:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class SimulateMouseClick
{
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
//Mouse actions
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

public static void Click()
{
    //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
    uint X = (uint)0;
    uint Y = (uint)0;
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
    Debug.LogError("SIMULATED A MOUSE CLICK JUST NOW...");
}

//...other code needed for the application
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative to simulating a <kbd>F5</kbd> key press would be to simply host the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control in the Window Forms application. You use the [WebBrowser.Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40x214wa.aspx) method to load your web page and then use a standard [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) and on each tick of the timer you just re-Navigate to the url which will reload the page.

Answer (score 5):

Simple one, add before Main

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Code inside Main/Method:

```
string className = "IEFrame";
string windowName = "New Tab - Windows Internet Explorer";
IntPtr IE = FindWindow(className, windowName);
if (IE == IntPtr.Zero)
{
   return;
}
SetForegroundWindow(IE);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.F5);
```

Note:

1. Add InputSimulator as reference. To download [Click here](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)
2. To find Class & Window name, use WinSpy++. To download [Click here](http://www.catch22.net/software/winspy-17)

Answer (score 4):

Easy, short and no need window focus:

Also [here](http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html) a usefull list of *Virtual Key Codes*

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
            const int VK_F5 = 0x74;

            IntPtr WindowToFind = FindWindow(null, "Google - Mozilla Firefox");

            PostMessage(WindowToFind, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_F5, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of forcing an <kbd>F5</kbd> keypress when you're just trying to get the page to postback, you can call a postback based on a JS event (even mousemove or timer_tick if you want it to fire all the time).  Use the code at http://weblogs.asp.net/mnolton/archive/2003/06/04/8260.aspx as a reference.