# Rotate the DataGrid, how to Rotate the direction / arrow keys

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, rotation, arrow-keys

We have rotated our `DataGrid` by "-90" successfully.
However, The arrow keys stayed as not rotated.

For example, When we press the UP-Arrow-key it goes left, instead UP, etc.

How can we rotate the Arrow keys to reflect the actual directions of the screen?

Thanks much for your help.

Comment: How did you rotate the DataGrid?

Comment: if you just used a RotateTransform with angle -90, it won´t change the datagrid behavior at all. so Arrow+Up means "Up" wich is Left rotated 90 degrees to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't imagine what for you've rotated dataGrid, but you can catch the keypress event and transform it to another key press (for example, left transform to up) like in this thread:

[Simulating Key Press c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp)