# SendKey.Send() Not working

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I'm using WPF and I imported the System.Windows.Form reference. Here's my code:

```
Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("wmplayer");
SetForegroundWindow(process[0].MainWindowHandle);
Thread.Sleep(200);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^p");
```

The Windows Media Player do Focus, but no keystroke is Received. Why?

Comment: It appears System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send sends keystrokes to the "active" application (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx).

I'm not entirely sure on what that means, but it might be limited to  the process it is executing in. Try using the Win32 api, check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp

Comment: @James it is definitely not limited to the process it is executing in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use WinAPI instead of SendKeys:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
public static void PressKey(Keys key, bool up) {
    const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
    const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
    if (up) {
        keybd_event((byte) key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr) 0);
    }
    else {
        keybd_event((byte) key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr) 0);
    }
}

void TestProc() {
    PressKey(Keys.ControlKey, false);
    PressKey(Keys.P, false);
    PressKey(Keys.P, true);
    PressKey(Keys.ControlKey, true);
}
```

Comment: Per the docs (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx), keybd_event has been superseded and SendInput should be used instead.

Comment: It's true, but this code works fine on all versions of Windows from XP to Windows 8 (Maybe the other too, but I have not tested). And in my opinion, to use SendInput is not as easy as keybd_event.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks now I can access MediaPlayPause button and so On...

Comment: keybd_event has been kept for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Anyone knows why sequence Keys.LWin, false + Keys.Shift , false + Keys.Left, false and than reverse sequence with true won't send window to other monitor, but it causes behavior like LWin was pressed separately, and then Shift + Left.

Answer (score 3):

In WPF applications you have to use [SendKeys.SendWait()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx) ([*English Documentation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx)) instead.

Just doublechecked it, while Send() is working for WinForms application, WPF throws an InvalidOperationException although both target .net 4.0.

Check above link for more information.