# C# equivalent to Java Robot class

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

What is the C# equivalent to Java Robot class for mouse pointer movements? As Actions class cannot be used directly for keyboard and mouse. I need to move my mouse pointer visually in selenium n c#. For example, if I want to access my mail from Rediffmail website, the mouse pointer should move to the address bar then to username and password textbox and log-in button. Mouse pointer should move along with the actions being performed in my tests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move mouse cursor using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050825/how-to-move-mouse-cursor-using-c)

Comment: I use [Windows input simulator library](https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator)...Please note that webdriver doesn't provide a direct way to get control position in screen coordinates with C# bindings...There are some properties but they are not yet implemented in webdriver... You will have to come up with your own logic to get control position in screen coordinate ..However, u can get coordinates relative to Dom using selenium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are looking out for C# modules equivalent to Java Robot class there can be three possible solutions :

- If you can tweak your requirement form *move the mouse pointer visually* to *highlight the **username** and **password** textbox*, you can take help of [ExecuteScript Method](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor_ExecuteScript.htm) from [IJavaScriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor.htm) Interface as follows :

  ```
  IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("username_field_xpath"))
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','backgroud: yellow; border: solid 2px red')", element);
  ```
- Another alternative would be to use the [Windows Input Simulator (C# SendInput Wrapper - Simulate Keyboard and Mouse)](https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator) as @Nish26 mentioned in her comments.
- The other alternative is the [Global Mouse and Keyboard Library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library) which uses the *Global Hooks* which can capture mouse and keyboard events from any application. These events are very similar to the ones that appear on Windows controls.

For the second and third options you won't find a direct way to interact through *WebDriver*. Perhaps you have to lookout for a tailor-made solution.