# C++ Simulating key presses only once

Tags: c++, keyboard

I have tried everything I found in google but nothing works. I want to press `A` for **5 seconds**, but everything presses it only once.It just releases it immediately. Pressing multiple times is not the answer because the key must be pressed for atleast 30ms.

```
const int KEYEVENT_KEYUP = 0x02;

keybd_event(0x41, 0, 0, 0);
Sleep(5000);
keybd_event(0x41, 0, KEYEVENT_KEYUP, 0);
```

Comment: Loop like a madman on the keybd_event with a thread maybe ?

Comment: @rak007 it can't be the best way to do it.

Comment: Look like it is unfortunately with the win API : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982409/simulate-a-keypress-for-x-seconds

Comment: Holding a key down is reinterpreted as repeated key presses *by the keyboard.*

Comment: How can I repeat it so fast. I tried while loop, but it was a lot slower than just pressing a key down. I am currently trying to make a new thread for it, but have no experience in c++ threads.

Comment: @rak007 Looks like the software I am doing this doesn't accept too fast taps. It must be pressed for 30ms or something. I am completely stuck now.

Comment: Still not solved