# Shortcut with holding more keys and one char with click in c# selenium automation

Tags: c#, selenium, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a shortcut with holding keys CRTL + ALT + E + CLICK on button. 
In selenium I'm trying to do this with like below
`var actions = new Actions(Driver)`
then 
`actions.KeyDown(Keys.Control + Keys.Alt).SendKeys("E").Click(Button).Perform();`

Method `SendKeys("E")` is doing `KeyDown` and then `KeyUp` and that's why, I can not create correct shortcut with click because I'm not holding `"E"`.

Any tips how to perform `KeyDown("E")` ?

EDIT: 
`actions.ClickAndHold(ActionButtons.Edit.Init());
 actions.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Alt + "e" + Keys.Clear);
 actions.Build().Perform();`

Also I find other way with ClickAndHold(). The principle is click and send sequence of keys and in the same time release click.
Any suggestions, how to do that ?

Comment: Use Robot class ,For Keyboard events keypress & keyRelease to press & release keys.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Can you send a reference please ?

Comment: You need to import java.awt.Robot;Robot rb = new Robot();
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);This code to press Ctrl + A keys

Comment: Maybe in java but I'm using c#

Comment: for reference 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402643/sendkey-send-not-working/11403269#11403269     2)https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4ff3770-c384-4526-9099-cf134be4dfcc/javaawtrobot-equivalent-in-net?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 actions.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Alt + "e").Click(Button).Perform();
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because when the click is performed, keys are not holded