# C# WPF: How to programmatically press a keyboard button?

Tags: c#, wpf

A WPF application has a `Test()` method that is called when a keyboard shortcut is pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

**The method call works because the string `test` is printed to the console, from the first line of the method.**

---

The method should programmatically press the key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select the text in any input field, but this does not happen.

**I tried 3 ways:**

---

**First:** The `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait()` method, which takes a string, where `^` is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - according to [**documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

```cs
private void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    SendKeys.SendWait("^A");
}
```

However, there is no pressing.

---

**Second:** Implementation via `user32.dll`, solution taken from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11403269/14519908):

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
public static void PressKey(Keys key, bool up)
{
    const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
    const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
    if (up)
        keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, (UIntPtr)0);
    else
        keybd_event((byte)key, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
}

private void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    PressKey(Keys.ControlKey, up: false);
    PressKey(Keys.A, up: false);
    PressKey(Keys.A, up: true);
    PressKey(Keys.ControlKey, up: true);
}
```

But in this case, nothing happens.

---

**Third:** Installed the package: `Install-Package InputSimulator`:

```cs
private static void Test(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    var simu = new InputSimulator();
    simu.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_A);
}
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/ay8vRtjA

There are no errors, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: IMO you should have some other view model/controller class that would have method to handle such key press. Then I would write unit test for that controller class to properly test the logic.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I've updated the question with a link to the full code if that can help somehow

Comment: When you say "in any input field", do you mean any input field in _your_ application or in _any_ application?

Comment: is the text field your trying to select all text in focus?

Comment: @VisualVincent I mean input field in **in any application**

Comment: @BenSteele yes, field in focus. I also try to press other keyboard buttons like `win`-key, but that also not work

Comment: I just tested this. The issue is because you're still holding down `ALT` when the code executes, making the resulting combination `CTRL + ALT + A`.

Comment: @VisualVincent indeed - it is. I would never have thought of it myself, now I understand why it was necessary to make tests with the output of all the keys pressed. And what is the right way to avoid this problem? Set a delay when executing a method? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key combination technically works, but the code executes before you have any time to release the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key, making the final combination <kbd>CTRL + ALT + A</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL + A</kbd>. I may be overlooking some simpler solution, but the way I found (mostly) works is:

- Intercept the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key

  - If <kbd>G</kbd> is pressed while <kbd>ALT</kbd> is down, execute the command
  - If <kbd>G</kbd> wasn't pressed, allow the keystroke through and send a simulated <kbd>ALT</kbd> (so that hotkeys in other applications can still be activated)

It's a hacky workaround and still messes up some regular functionality (for instance if you press a hotkey like <kbd>ALT + A</kbd> to open a menu, the menu will close as soon as you release <kbd>ALT</kbd>), but it makes your hotkey work.

I used a library that I created a couple of years back, called [InputHelper](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper), to set up a global keyboard hook to intercept the keystrokes and execute the hotkey. I've yet to publish this to NuGet, so for now you'll have to download it via [Releases](https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/releases) and add the DLL as a reference in your project.

You'll also need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HotkeyTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        InputHelper.Hooks.KeyboardHook kbHook = new InputHelper.Hooks.KeyboardHook();

        bool AltHotkeyConsumed = false;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            kbHook.KeyDown += KeyboardHook_KeyDown;
            kbHook.KeyUp += KeyboardHook_KeyUp;
        }

        private void KeyboardHook_KeyUp(object sender, InputHelper.EventArgs.KeyboardHookEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.LMenu || e.KeyCode == Keys.RMenu)
            {
                if(!AltHotkeyConsumed)
                    // If no hotkey was consumed, press the key again (otherwise it will just be blocked altogether)
                    InputHelper.Keyboard.PressKey(e.KeyCode);
                else
                    AltHotkeyConsumed = false;
            }
        }

        private void KeyboardHook_KeyDown(object sender, InputHelper.EventArgs.KeyboardHookEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.LMenu || e.KeyCode == Keys.RMenu)
                e.Block = true;

            if(e.Modifiers == InputHelper.ModifierKeys.Alt)
            {
                if(e.KeyCode == Keys.G)
                {
                    Test();
                    AltHotkeyConsumed = true;
                    e.Block = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Block = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void Test()
        {
            InputHelper.Keyboard.SetKeyState(Keys.LControlKey, true);
            InputHelper.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.A);
            InputHelper.Keyboard.SetKeyState(Keys.LControlKey, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you replace `alt` with `control`, then when you try to press `CTRL+A` yourself, the text will not be selected, but will simply add the character "a" to the text. How to avoid it?

Comment: @denisnumb When the modifier key(s) (in this case `CTRL`) are the same as the hotkeys you don't need all the extra code. A simple `KeyDown` hook is all you require: https://pastebin.com/CBNcpbEy

Comment: My initial solution was a hacky one, and mainly focused at resolving the problem at hand. Remapping modifiers only for certain hotkeys is not a simple task as it involves tricking the OS that you're in a different keyboard state. If you do have a case where you need to remap `CTRL` to another modifier, off the top of my head you would likely have to track which keys were pressed after `CTRL`, and once you've determined that they're not a hotkey, replay them again in the correct order without having the keyboard hook block them.