# unfocusable form C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I need to create unfocusable form in C#.
On that form there will be button. After pressing that button I want to paste content of System.Clipboard to the place where the cursot is.
This is what I have till now:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    const int WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000;
    const int WS_EX_TOPMOST = 0x00000008;
    const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;
    const int WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021;
    const int WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE = 0x00000100;
    const int MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT = 4;
    const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
    //const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;
    const int WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;
    const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
    const int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000;
    const int WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000;
    const int WS_CAPTION = WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME;
    const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000;

    protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation { get { return true; } }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams ret = base.CreateParams;
            ret.Style = WS_THICKFRAME |
               WS_CHILD | 
                WS_CAPTION | 
                WS_SYSMENU;
            ret.ExStyle |= WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | 
                WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW |
                WS_EX_TOPMOST | 
                WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
            ret.X = this.Location.X;
            ret.Y = this.Location.Y;
            return ret;
        }
    }

    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText("text1 text2");
        SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
    }
}
```

The form is not the main form of my application.
The code works only if the focus is in my application. If I focus notepad or any other program clipboard content is not pasted to it.
Any one can help with this?

Comment: "After pressing that button I want to paste content of System.Clipboard to the place where the cursor is." - I don't understand this requirement: Surely the cursor will always be over the button that you just pressed? Or do you mean that you press the button via the keyboard?

Comment: I don't meen Mouse cursor, but place where keyboard input was last placed.

Comment: Is hte problem with making it unfocasable or pasting?

Comment: If the form will not steel focus, I will be able to paste text from clipboard to current window. This works but only inside my application.

Answer (score 0):

I think at first you must determ a window to send a keystroke.

I found a good [sample at codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18366/Sending-Keystrokes-to-another-Application-in-C) and many questions here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp) and [other](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=send+key+to+window+C%23&submit=search)

Comment: Thanks, but I already read that. The problem is with identifying prevoius program.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to title your questions properly. I believe you are looking for a clipboard monitor snippet. You will have to register your appplication to intercept clipboard changed events.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SetClipboardViewer(IntPtr hWndNewViewer);

_ClipboardViewerNext = SetClipboardViewer(this.Handle);

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch ((Win32.Msgs)m.Msg)
    {
        case Win32.Msgs.WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
        // Handle clipboard changed
        break;
        // ... 
   }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/621582/612717) and this [article](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/clipboardmonitor.aspx).

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to paste text from clipboard to the window that has focus. For example if I have notepad opened and i click Paste button on my form, text from clipboard should be pasted to notepad.

Answer (score 0):

When your application receives focus, it will be sent the `WM_ACTIVATE` or `WM_ACTIVATEAPP` messages which contain the previous focused window handle. You can then set the focus back using `SetActiveWindow`. You should still receive the click as usual.

Comment: Unfortunately this works only inside my application. If the focus was in other program, than WM_ACTIVATE does not have information about that program.