# C# How to press any keyboard key every few min/seconds?

Tags: c#

I am looking for a code that will press any keyboard key every 50 seconds, lets say the key is the number 5 key.

Just make sure that it wont just type 5, I want it to press the key itself.

EDIT: i just want it to press any keyboard key thats all. like if its shift or capslock or whatever

Comment: *wont just type 5, i just want it to press the key itself*, do you mean like magic the key being pressed ?

Comment: Dint get you please add some more information for better explanation..!!

Comment: Software can't really do any hardware physical things, you know?

Comment: Why do you want to press the key? Is it to keep the machine awake? In that case, there are better ways to accomplish this. Or is this to use with a particular application?

Comment: ye i just want it to keep pressing 5 or any other key every few seconds..

Comment: he just want to count the pressed keyboard.

Comment: we're not trolling you, it's just unclear the reason why you want to do this. There may be other ways.

Comment: No one is trying to troll you. The question is extremely unclear - you can't have software press keys for you. What is it that you are _actually_ trying to achieve that pressing 5 repeatedly will solve?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qExIeZtt8KA might help

Comment: Have a look into this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you want to achieve this programmatically.

If this is the case you can use:

```
    SendKeys.Send({NUMPAD5});
    SendKeys.Send({HOME});
```

And so on.
For the timer part:

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);     // Everytime timer ticks, timer_Tick will be called
        timer.Interval = (1000) * (50);             // Timer will tick every 50 second
        timer.Enabled = true;                       // Enable the timer
        timer.Start();                              // Start the timer

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send({NUMPAD5});
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `SendKey class`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [SendKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) in combination with a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Software can simulate a key press by various methods, ie, mimic what would happen when the key was pressed.  What it cannot do is press the key.  You would need to create a robot that would press the key every so often.

Can you provide the context in which you are trying to achieve this.  There may be better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int countTypeA = 0;
        private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.A:
                    ++countTypeA;
                    Console.WriteLine(countTypeA.ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }
```