# Using .NET: How Can I Edit an HTML Form Input Text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I want to use .NET to fill a input text box, that's inside an HTML form inside an IE window.

This HTML form is already open inside an Internet Explorer window. So my program doesn't need to open IE, nor does my program need to open an HTML page because, the HTML page is already open.

Can someone point me in the right direction please - how do I edit an input text box inside an IE window?

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Structure your query properly. What is HTML form ? Is it other application or your own? Or you are running your own code and values not showing up?

Comment: Use javascript and ajax.

Comment: Are you saying you want a *desktop* application to fill in a textbox in a website that is open in an **external** instance of Internet Explorer?  Or is that instance of Internet Explorer in a control **within** your desktop application?

Answer (score 0):

hardcore version 
Look at this thread [Simulating Key Press c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp)

I assume you know layout of the form:

1. write function that will invoke keypress events InvokeKey, take care of tab and space keys as well
2. Write a function that will convert string to series of keypress events let's say WriteItForMe(string input) using function in 1.
3. To fill form do this (example)

   ```
   WriteItForMe("Michael");    
   InvokeKey("#tab");    
   WriteItForMe("Scofield");   
   InvokeKey("#tab");
   ```

etc.