# SendKeys.Send("hello"); continuously sending string how can i send only once

Tags: c#, sendkeys

This code is continuously sending a string. I need a solution which can send the supplied string only once by clicking a button in the window which has the focus.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("This is a test...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show all relevant code?

Comment: How many times does it send keys with this code? Is this the only code? Are you sure this is not interfering with some other logic?

Comment: @rory.ap That code seems to repro the "problem" for me. Does it not for you?

Comment: I also found this and it was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be the fact that the `button1` control has the focus, and when you send certain keys to it (like the space in your example), it triggers the `Click` event, and you end up in an infinite loop.

Try adding a `TextBox` to your form and then set focus to that first (or if you already know the thing that should receive the text, ensure that it has the focus before you call `SendKeys`):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Focus();
    SendKeys.Send("This is a test...");
}
```

Comment: Space can trigger the click event on buttons (I verified this on a focused button in one of my winforms applications)