# Unity keyboard control (press on a key from C# script)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keyboard

How can I press a key from the C# script? All I found it's just how to get click on a key, I did not find how to press programmatically on a key. How can I do that?

I want to make the key pressed. Not to check if the key is pressed.

For example, I want to press `Enter` with my C# script.

Comment: Why do you need to? You could be going about it the wrong way

Comment: I want to make the key pressed

Comment: There's not a motor in the key so you can't have the code press it. Maybe if you make a robot finger that can press it ;) But I have a feeling you're not actually interested in the key being pressed, you're interested in *something* reacting as if the key was pressed. So, what is that *something* in your use case?

Comment: Ok, I have an idea. Thanks

Comment: The [command pattern](https://www.habrador.com/tutorials/programming-patterns/1-command-pattern/) might be of interest if that *something* is other parts of the code you are writing.

Comment: Thanks. Have a good day

Comment: FWIW OP may have actually been wanting to simulate a keypress. I have that need to use a VR keyboard to simulate keypresses so that standard input events are generated so a 3rd-party component can react as if a key has been pressed without me directly calling anything in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in vanilla Unity to simulate a keypress, I believe. Based on what you require, it's most likely that you're trying to simulate an event happening. What you could do is simply make a function that's going to execute the event that's going to happen *when you press ENTER* and then call that event whenever it's supposed to be executed.

It's already been discussed here :
[How to simulate a key press on button click - Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48930193/how-to-simulate-a-key-press-on-button-click-unity)