# How to send Space key to windows?

Tags: c#, space, sendkeys

I tried to send it with `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(String)` method 
but it doesn't have `{SPACE}` in it.

> Attention : I don't want to write space in something i tried to send `" "` but i want to send real space key to windows

Comment: There are multiple ways to go about this, depending on what precisely you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp But generally it is the kind of thing you are better of not doing and learn to live without it. This goes deep into unmanaged code.

Comment: Thanks , i know it's not a good way , but i want to write an small bot to send spaces and control a game.