# C#, Minecraft and Keybidings. Every keyboard event (except Control) is detected as "SOH\SOH]SOH"

Tags: java, c#, keyboard, minecraft

iam trying to set controlls in Java Edition Minecraft via my C# App:

```
using System;
using WindowsInput.Native;
using WindowsInput;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MinecraftController
{
    class Program
    {
        const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        const int VK_F5 = 68;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
                Process mc;
                foreach (Process proc in processes)
                {

                    if (proc.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains("java"))
                    {
                        if (proc.MainWindowTitle.ToLower().Contains("minecraft"))
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine(proc.ProcessName);
                            Console.WriteLine(proc.MainWindowTitle);
                            mc = proc;
                            PostMessage(mc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, 17, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }


                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
        }





    }
}
```

I tried to every numbers, and 0x format, and i changed int to string, byte, decimal. Everything gives me result `SOH\SOH]SOH`. I tried to use WindowsInput library with VK, but a result is the same every time. Have you idea what to do, to have correct key biddings via c# app? I want to create bot to minecraft, i dont want to cheat, just make some fun for my kid. [image: soh in minecraft]

Comment: you could simulate the key pressing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp

Comment: i found that only way to simulate keys via directx is robot pressing buttons on keyboard . your solution is not gona work