# How to send a recording command to OBS in C#?

Tags: c#, frontend, obs

Softwares such as G HUB allow user to toggle streaming/recording without binding hotkeys.

[image]

I would like to do the same in my program which is written in C#. I took a look at the frontend API documents but I am stil unsure how to implement such tasks in C#. Any ideas to do this without using websocket? I don't want to install external plugin in obs

Comment: [Some hacks on simulating input as if you did it on your keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes I know but I would like to use a diffrent approach

Comment: Not many options, you either pretend to be a human and interact via OS, or you find a C# library with OBS API (which I'm not sure even exists, maybe [this](https://github.com/ilosvideos/libobs-sharp))