# Scheduling VBS, with shell and sendkeys, to run whether user is logged on or not

Tags: vbscript, automation, scheduled-tasks

I've been working on this issue for a few days now. I have a script that I need to run, it will run a CLI program, and enter login info via sendkeys. This will run ok if the option to "Run only when the user is logged on".

However, once I select to "Run whether user is logged on or not", the scheduled task shows that it ran, but it's not evident that it did so. How else may I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendkeys is programmed to interact with the active user's interface. So if your computer is locked, it will not do anything because the interface is locked.

Depending on the CLI, it may have parameters to login on initialization.

Given the test.bat file:

```
CD C:\Program Files\example\exampleclidirectory
set user=username
set pswd=password
cmdline.exe -user %user% -password %pswd%
```

If parameters are not an option, try to use SendMessage/PostMessage and FindWindow instead of Sendkeys. This should be available in C# or VB. But I'd suggest C#.

Here's some resources on that:

http://www.codingvision.net/miscellaneous/c-send-text-to-notepad

[I can't understand how to use SendMessage or PostMessage calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808540/i-cant-understand-how-to-use-sendmessage-or-postmessage-calls)

And that should give you some method of entering in the data you need to get the program rolling.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The CLI does actually take input from a file for the username/password.